# Array to Query with '&' instead of '&apm;' in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to build a query from an array.

I did try to use `http_build_query` function but it results `&amp;` instead of `&`

So, I try to create my own function but I have this error:

> Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could
>   not be converted to string

This is my code:

```
$params = [
'foo' => $reuest->foo,
'baz' => 'boom',
'cow' => 'milk',
'php' => 'hypertext processor']

        $paramsJoined = array();

        foreach($params as $param => $value) {
            $paramsJoined[] = "$param=$value";
        }

        $query = implode('&', $paramsJoined);
```

Comment: "I did try to use http_build_query function but it results &amp; instead of &" — It should not do that. Are you sure you aren't running the result of `http)build_query` through something which makes the string safe for HTML?

Comment: "I try to create my own function" — You forgot to URL encode the keys and values

Comment: "I have this error" — Doesn't it tell you which line the error occurs on?

Comment: @Quentin i did try this `$paramsJoined[] = $param . "=" . rawurlencode($value);` but it returns: `rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: So which value isn't a string? What is it? Look at how you can convert it to what you want.

Comment: @Quentin You are absolutely right. The one the is Requested from GET is a object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
    'cow' => 'milk',
    'php' => 'hypertext processor'];

  echo http_build_query($data); 
?>
```

---

Output:

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

**Edit 1:**

You may alternatively use:

`echo http_build_query($data, '', '&');`

Comment: Unfortunately it returns: `foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor` how can i change `&amp;` to ` &`?

Comment: @DmitryMalys after you get the string with `&amp;` store that in a variable and use `$new_string =  str_replace("&amp;","&",$string_variable);`

Comment: @DmitryMalys I have even made an edit to answer check that out.

Comment: @DmitryMalys you may also try the alternative that I suggested. You know just to so you have optimized solution.